# How does index refresh interval work in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I set `index.refresh_interval=-1`, that means the indexReader would not be refreshed forever, but why I still could find some new docs after a while of indexing? Is there any other parameter to control the index refresh?

Let's suppose there is a parameter called `maxDocsRefresh`, that means when the new docs reach a limitation IndexReader would refresh automatically. However, the problem is that there could be some unsearchable docs since part of the docs didn't reach the limitation of index refresh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `refersh_interval` setting provides a near real-time search ability to elasticsearch.

The following [article](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/translog.html) provides a great explanation of what exactly occurs during a refresh and the difference between a `refresh` and `flush`.

Simply put `refresh` allows for the documents to be searchable before the lucene segment is flushed/commited to disk. However if you disable refresh it would eventually commit when the translog reaches a certain thresold and this would make the data searchable.

The following  [documents](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/translog.html) shows the parameters that can be used to tweak the flush settings.